# How to get set object values properly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using just one small ng-controller and I have something like this:

```
<select ng-model="character" ng-options="ch.name for ch in characters"></select>

{{character}} <-- good, even {{character.attr}} works

{{attr}} <-- bad, not updated when select changes*


...function($scope){

$scope.character = characters[0]; <-- good, get/set object as spected

$scope.attr = $scope.character.name; <-- bad, it just sets an initial value*
                                         which is not updated when select does

}
```

`$scope.attr = character.name, $scope.attr = $scope.character['name']`, doesn't work. So functions like this will never work:

```
$scope.attack_array = function(i){  <-- field or whole object cant be sent **
  let character = characters[i];
  let array..
}

$scope.attack_array($scope.character.index) <-- how do i get the separated values by each field?
```

Comment: Please share `characters` structure

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN `var characters = [{"id": 0, "type": "unsc", "name": "sgt johnson"}, {...} ];` is out of angular.module( ).controller( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the view to this

```
<select ng-model="character" ng-init="character = characters[0]" ng-options="ch.name for ch in characters"></select>
```

You can access the selected value like this `$scope.attr = $scope.character.name;`.
hope this will work. Let me know. If you want anything  else.

Comment: thanks biswajit-rout , i edited setting `ng-init="character = characters[0]"` and/or `ng-init="attr = character.name"`, now the value of attr is displayed but still is constant/static. `$scope.attr = $scope.var.field` is a problem yet

Comment: Can you create a sample fiddle of your code?. I that will clear all our confusion.

Comment: I did not get it to work on jsfiddle.. there it goes worse but this is a copy-paste of my project (characters are listed on select) [link](https://jsfiddle.net/vkddubyb/26/)

Comment: Can you check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/biswajit_rout/f1o0jj58/5/  . I think it will  meet your requirement. Let me know if you have any other query.